# IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(): No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

When I try to add a migration:
`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project Entities --startup-project WinUI3Controller`

I get this exception:
`No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.`

I think that EntityFramworkCore don't find my ConfigureServices() method because when I add a `Console.WriteLine()` at the first line of the method, nothing appears in console.
As the method should be in the Program class, it makes sens that's not working.
The issue is that the Program class is auto generated by WinUI3.

Am I on the right track? What am I missing?

#### The corresponding code as context :

In "WinUI3Controller" project:

**App.xaml.cs**:

```cs
public partial class App : Appliaction
{
    ...

    private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddSingleton<IExempleService, ExempleService>();
        services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
            options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            },
            ServiceLifetime.Scoped
        );

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WinUI3Solution_DBTest;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=true"
  }
}
```

In "Entities" project:

**MyContext.cs**:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public MyContext() { }
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }
}
```

Comment: Do you have other data contexts too?
`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project Entities --startup-project WinUI3Controller --context MyContext`

Comment: Try declaring a partial program class,

`public partial class Program` in the startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to look into [design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) approach. Add to the project used to run migrations (and all required packages):

```cs
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyContext>
{
    public MyContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .Build();
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
        optionsBuilder
           .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        return new MyContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've missed calling ConfigureServices() in your application startup.
You can call it in the App constructor and then work with its IServiceProvider return type.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code in you `MyContext` class

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your connection string here");
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I don't want to have my connection string in the code of my Entities project.